# Optimize MySQL query for group_concat function

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, myisam

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE link.stop, stop.common_name, locality.name, stop.bearing, stop.latitude, stop.longitude
FROM service
JOIN pattern ON pattern.service = service.code
JOIN link ON link.section = pattern.section
JOIN naptan.stop ON stop.atco_code = link.stop
JOIN naptan.locality ON locality.code = stop.nptg_locality_ref
GROUP BY link.stop
```

The above query takes roughly 800ms - 1000ms to run.

If I append a `group_concat` statement the query then takes 8 - 10 seconds:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE link.stop, link.stop, stop.common_name, locality.name, stop.bearing, stop.latitude, stop.longitude, group_concat(service.line) lines
```

How can I change this query so that it runs in less than 2 seconds with the `group_concat` statement?

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/414fe

`EXPLAIN` statements for both queries: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN176.png

Comment: Can you please post the result of `EXPLAIN` for this query? (I noticed that one of your tables is in MyISAM and has a geospatial index.)  You might want to read this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: @OllieJones Hi Ollie, I have added a `EXPLAIN` to the question, apologies for not mentioning the MyISAM table

Comment: To my mind, and to a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution.

Comment: Why do you need the last two joins?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the two more selected fields to the query, I removed them as they are irrelevant, but I understand that you need to know they are there for a reason

Comment: When you're optimizing a GROUP BY query, all the columns of the result set are relevant. That's because compound indexes can make a big performance difference.

Comment: @OllieJones Based on that information I have made sure that all of the selected fields are now in the query

Comment: Now, please provide EXPLAINs for both queries with all the fields..

Comment: @RickJames Sure, I will update them now

Comment: @RickJames The link for `EXPLAIN` now shows both statements, both updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How long does this query take?

```
SELECT p.section, GROUP_CONCAT(s.line)
FROM pattern p join
     service s
     ON p.service = s.code
GROUP BY p.section
```

I am thinking that you can do the `group_concat()` in a subquery, so the outer query does not need an aggregation.  This can speed queries when there is one table in the subquery.  In your case, there are two.

The final results would be something like:

link.section = pattern.section

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE . . .,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.line)
        FROM pattern p join
             service s
             ON p.service = s.code
        WHERE p.section = link.section
       ) as lines
FROM link JOIN
     naptan.stop
     ON stop.atco_code = link.stop JOIN
     naptan.locality
     ON locality.code = stop.nptg_locality_ref;
```

For this query, you want the following additional indexes:  `pattern(section, service)` and `service(code, line)`.

I don't know if this will work, but it is worth a try.

Note:  this is assuming that you really don't need the `group by` for the rest of the columns.

Comment: The first query you put takes 0.064 seconds. The query in total takes around 1.5 seconds on average! Thanks very much :-)

Comment: @jskidd3 . . . Cool.  I don't like the fact that MySQL will not use indexes efficiently for `group by` (perhaps in some future release).  I *wish* it implemented your original version as if written like above, but I'm happy that this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

A remark: You're using the [nonstandard MySQL extension to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html). It happens to work for you because `link.stop` is joined to `stop.atco_code`, which itself is a primary key.  But you need to be very careful with this.

I suggest you add some compound indexes. You join in to `pattern` on `service` and join out based on `section`. So add this index.

```
ALTER TABLE pattern ADD INDEX service_section (service, section, line);
```

This will let the query use just the index, and not have to hit the table itself to retrieve the information needed for the JOIN or your `GROUP_CONCAT()` operation.  (You might also delete the index on just `service`, this new index makes it redundant).

Similarly, you want to create an index `(section, stop)` on the `link` table, and get rid of the index on just `section`.

On `stop`, you're using most of the columns, and you already have an index (PK) on `atco_code`, so let this one be.

Finally, on `locality` put an index on `(code,name)`.

All this indexing monkey business should cut down the amount of work MySQL must do to satisfy your query.

Now look, as soon as you add `WHERE anything = anything` to the query, you may need to add a column to one or more of these indexes.  You definitely should read up on [multi-column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) [indexing](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) and [grouping](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-optimization.html); good indexing is a critical success factor for your kind of data.

You should also run `ANALYZE TABLE xxxx` on each of your tables after inserting lots of rows, to make sure the query optimizer can see appropriate information about the content of the table and indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ollie. I will read up on what you have suggested. Regarding your suggestions, the query now takes roughly 10 seconds to execute and 1.5 seconds to fetch. For what it's worth, there are 4,000 rows being returned. I have created another SQL Fiddle to show the changes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0db4